# Can I generate Service and Interface classes in a Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022, scaffolding

I have a Core Web API project (.net 6.0) where I have used scaffolding to generate the EF objects based on the tables in my Database. I have then used "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator" to generate some simple controllers based on the Entity Objects.

Now, is there any way to also generate the Service Classes and interface classes?  Basically, creating CRUD methods in the Service class. It seems like a very repeatable process so anything that could be generate would be helpful.

Comment: Surely if you're using EF, you already have CRUD via the DbContext/DbSets. If you want to add a layer on top of EF, eg. repository, I think you'll have to implement it manually.

Comment: You could try this package to avoid wrting a lot of codes. https://github.com/OfferingSolutions/Entity-Framework-Core-Generic-Repository